# Any way to force .load on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, google-chrome, webkit

I have a very simple function that is getting image data and than places it, also after that it will run sizeImages(); function that will resize image proportionally to the browser size. The problem here is that it works on every browser except Chrome (webkit). It is sizing correctly the first time I click on it, but after I click on it again it will not do it. So I'm askin' if there any option for me to force it to work?

```
$.get("getBg.php", {
    img: (this).id
},
function(data){
    $("#bg").html(data);
    $("#bgImage").load(function() {
        sizeImages();
    });
});
```

Comment: BTW I fixed it delaying it for 10 miliseconds and now it works for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is related to the problem that (if an image is in the browser cache), then it may load immediately upon creation.  If the "load" handler is attached after creation, then the load event has already fired before your handler was attached and your load handler will never get called.

The way you typically solve this is to make sure your code goes in this order:

```
var myImg = new Image();
myImg.onload = myLoadFunc;
myImg.src = "set URL here";
```

This ensures that the load handler is set before the image can possibly be loaded.

Your code example is definitely susceptible to this issue as you're creating the fully specified image tags before attaching the load handler.

David's example probably doesn't work because ".live" relies on event propagation which I don't believe works for the load event (I think it was mostly designed for mouse or key events).

If you need the load event to fire, you'll have to create the image object (without src set on it yet), attach the load handler and then set the src to make sure you get the load event.  It also may be possible to create the HTML, then attach the load event and then check if the image is already loaded and if so, call the load event manually though that isn't as safe as my code example above.  If you're creating the image from HTML, it's also safe to specify the onload handler in the HTML.